# Haskell *** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list

Tags: list, haskell

this function is to find out how many elements in list A is smaller than the smallest element in list B

every time the recursion happens the length list of A is reduce until emepty.

however... it only return the Exception: Prelude.head: empty list 
not even a 0..

why it is happened?

```
compareSmall::[Card] -> [Card] -> Int
compareSmall [] _ = 0
compareSmall _ [] = 0
compareSmall (x:xs) (y:ys) =         
        if   rank  (head tnt1) < rank (head tnt2)   then         
            1 + compareSmall (tail tnt1) (tnt2)      
        else if  rank (head (tail tnt1)) == rank (head tnt2) then       
            0 + compareSmall (tail tnt1) (tnt2)       
        else 
            0 + compareSmall (tail tnt1) (tnt2)
                    where tnt1 = rankCard (x:xs)
                          tnt2 = rankCard (y:ys)
```

Comment: I think problem is in `rankCard`. Check it return value. Possibly it returns empty list and then `head tnt1` fails with exception.

Comment: also, it's worth trying to write code without using `head`, using pattern matching instead, if possible...

Comment: there is also be a problem if `rankCard` returne a singleton list - for `rank (head (tail tnt1))` in the first `else if` branch would then be an error.

Comment: could you please explain your second if statement? it seems you are doing a `if condition then "something" else "the same thing"` I see a small optimization step (or a possible logic error). also there is no need for `(x:xs)` and `(y:ys)` you are never using `x`,`y`,`xs` or `ys`, and another advice, your indentation/aligment seems to be misleading - the last else branch is inside the other else branch - not on the same level.

Comment: Try writing this without `head` and without `tail`. Run GHC or GHCi with the `-Wall` option and fix any warnings you get. (Take two aspirin and call me in the morning.)

Comment: As an aside, you can simplify your code to something like this: `import Data.Ord (comparing); compareSmall [] _ = 0; compareSmall _ [] = 0; compareSmall as bs = length $ filter (< minimumBy (comparing rank) bs) as`. I don’t know what `rankCard` is supposed to mean, though.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why

Your problem lies in `rankCard` returning an empty list and thus `tnt1` or `tnt2` is `[]` at some point. You then get the error when you do `head tnt1`, because `head` is a partial function, and will throw an exception on an empty list instead of a `Maybe`.

This is happening in the call `else if  rank (head (tail tnt1)) == rank (head tnt2) then`, specifically `(head (tail tnt1))` giving an error when `tnt1` is a list containing 1 element.

#### Fixing it

It seems your second if-statement is not needed since you never modify your `tnt2` list, so it will be caught the final else by letting the recursion run one more time and not throw any errors. Your code could just be

```
compareSmall :: [Card] -> [Card] -> Int
compareSmall [] _ = 0
compareSmall _ [] = 0
compareSmall a b  =
  if rank (head tnt1) < rank (head tnt2)   then
    1 + compareSmall (tail tnt1) b
  else
    0 + compareSmall (tail tnt1) b
  where
    tnt1 = rankCard a
    tnt2 = rankCard b
```

---

Side-note: Haskell has syntax for keeping the whole list when you pattern match it, so you could do

```
compareSmall a@(x:xs) b@(y:ys) =
  ...
  where
    tnt1 = rank a
    tnt2 = rank b
```

if you ever need that.

Comment: I understand!! it really helps me to learn how the Haskell works, Thank you very much!

Comment: If you feel like it answered the question, could you mark it as the answer, just to "close" it? :)